# React JS Unreachable code no-unreachable

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React.js. I searched the solution to my problem about 2 days ago, but I don't know what is the problem.

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    {
      this.state.menus.map((item_main, index_main) => {
        return (<h1 key={item_main.main_name}>{item_main.main_name}</h1>);
           var subs = this.state.menus[index_main].subs.map((item_sub, index_sub) => {
             return(<h4 key={item_sub.sub_name}>{item_sub.sub_name}</h4>)
           })

       })
    }
  </div>
);
```

}

If I replace the 'return' to 'console.log', it looks good in console, but on the web does not appear.

Comment: This should render the names of the item_mains. But the subs variable is after the render which is why it doesn't show. What data do you see right now? And what would be the expected behaviour?

Comment: React doesn't change what the `return` statement does, that's the same as in ordinary JS. The `var subs = ...` after a `return` statement doesn't make sense. But how you should write this instead may be React-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unreachable aspect part of your code comes from the fact that once you `return`, then the line below it won't execute. In this case:

```
var subs = this.state.menus[index_main].subs.map((item_sub, index_sub) => {
  return(<h4 key={item_sub.sub_name}>{item_sub.sub_name}</h4>)
 })
```

will never run with the return. This is what is causing your `no-unreachable` linter error to fire.

From your post it's a bit ambiguous about what your desired behavior is, but my best guess is that you want an `<h1>` for each item, followed by an `<h4>` for each of your submenu items. In that case your code should look something like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    {
      this.state.menus.map((item_main, index_main) => {
           var subs = this.state.menus[index_main].subs.map((item_sub, index_sub) => {
             return(<h4 key={item_sub.sub_name}>{item_sub.sub_name}</h4>)
           });
            return (
              <div>
                <h1 key={item_main.main_name}>{item_main.main_name}</h1>
                {subs}
              </div>
            );

       })
    }
  </div>
);
```

You can also use a `<Fragment>` as the outer wrapper, but I didn't include that here for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Ohh, now I understand! Thank you so much!